# Data not sorted properly using str_to_date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of dates in a table in the format `August 31, 2013, 5:02 am`. I need to convert these to dates and sort on the dates. I'm using the below query, but it returns the dates in a strange way.

```
SELECT name, date, link FROM table_name ORDER BY str_to_date(date, '%M %e, %Y, %l %p')
```

So, for an example set of data, I have:

```
August 31, 2013, 5:02 am
October 10, 2013, 2:14 pm
October 14, 2013, 7:00 pm
October 22, 2013, 1:46 pm
October 22, 2013, 2:47 pm
```

When the query runs, however, the sorting occurs like this:

```
August 31, 2013, 5:02 am
October 22, 2013, 2:47 pm
October 22, 2013, 1:46 pm
October 10, 2013, 2:14 pm
October 14, 2013, 7:00 pm
```

What do I need to do to correct the query and display the data properly?

Comment: Don't you need minutes? `'%M %e, %Y, %l:%i %p'` And why, why, why are you storing dates as strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you use `%l:%i` for the time part, instead of just `%l`:

```
mysql> SELECT str_to_date(date, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i %p') FROM table_name ORDER BY str_to_date(date, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i %p');
+-----------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date(timestamp, '%M %e, %Y, %l:%i %p') |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2013-08-31 05:02:00                           |
| 2013-10-10 14:14:00                           |
| 2013-10-14 19:00:00                           |
| 2013-10-22 13:46:00                           |
| 2013-10-22 14:47:00                           |
+-----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. It's always the simplest things. Thank you!